# How to share on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, slcomposeviewcontroller

The code:

```
let shareFB : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
shareFB.setInitialText("test")

self.presentViewController(shareFB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

works great in the simulator but not on device. Why? Is there another method of doing this. I need to be able to post a message and a link.

Comment: Is Facebook setup on the device?

Comment: Yes, everything works but no initialtext is shown...

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that it was the Setinitialtext that didn't worked.. been working all day with my app - pretty empty in my head

Comment: @JonP, rase a bug report to apple,i ve just test it !

Comment: @JonP, you may need to implement it manually here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios